# How to add custom fields to the order_invoice.tpl, OpenCart 2.0

Tags: php, opencart

I have searched far and wide for this answer on the web, and nobody seems to have an answer. I know that in OpenCart 2.0 you have the ability to add custom fields in the registration process. I have added 3. I see that they are showing up in the Order Details section of an order, but I need them to show up on the printed invoice too. The code that outputs the custom fields in the order_info.tpl is as follows:

```
<?php foreach ($account_custom_fields as $custom_field) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $custom_field['name']; ?>:</td>
    <td><?php echo $custom_field['value']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

I attempted to just insert that into order_invoice.tpl but I am receiving the error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: account_custom_fields in /home/raphaelseventworks.com/www/ncbaorders/admin/view/template/sale/order_invoice.tpl on line 64Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/raphaelseventworks.com/www/ncbaorders/admin/view/template/sale/order_invoice.tpl on line 64

I don't know enough about OpenCart to know which files make up the order_invoice.tpl. Can someone help me out? I believe one answer I saw to this same question is, "It's difficult." I know it's not a simple process, but if you can point me to the right files, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Where does `$account_custom_fields` come from in the place where it works?

Comment: Ok, you must set data in controller... So, this is path to the file: admin->controller->sale and there you will find order.php file. On line  ~1887  you will find: public function invoice() ... That function creates invoice and loads order_invoice.tpl....

Comment: You are a life saver! Thank you! I copied the custom fields section into public function invoice(), and it worked like a dream!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to nevermind for the hint!

In admin->controller->sale->order.php, I found on line 863 the section for Custom Fields. I copied that whole section into the bottom of public function invoice(). Worked like a dream. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: could you help me to implement it on my store?

Answer (score 0):

**[VQMOD] Add Custom Fields To Order Invoice**
https://github.com/kanenas/vqmod-opencart-admin-add-custom-fields-order-invoice

**Opencart**: v.2.1.0.2
**Attention**: You have to install [VQMOD] for Opencart ( https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/releases ) for this to work!

1. Upload the file `knns_admin_add_custom_fields_order_invoice.xml` inside the folder `/vqmod/xml/`.