# How to add custom fields to the order invoice - OpenCart 2

Tags: opencart

I know that in OpenCart 2.3 you have the ability to add custom fields in the registration process. I have added 3. I see that they are showing up in the Order Details section of an order, but I need them to show up on the printed invoice too. HELP :(

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214811/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-the-order-invoice-tpl-opencart-2-0

Comment: i can't understand what he copy